# Innodb Mysql) Fulltext Index has stopped indexing after a certain point in time

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, innodb

I am currently maintaining a live board service and the biggest table that contains all the posts and replies has three full text indexes defined with different columns.

The searching is done in ngram and in BOOLEAN mode. Searching with MATCH...AGAINST has worked flawlessly for the last couple of years until this September.

It will no longer index data after a certain date. The small catch is that the most recently inserted rows (< 10 minutes ago) actually do show up then disappear.

I believe there are two tables that store the data for full text indexes, which are

1. INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE
2. INNODB_FT_INDEX_CACHE

New rows are put into the CACHE and is automatically flushed into the TABLE on a regular basis. The searching works for recent rows probably because it hasn't yet been flushed into the TABLE. (directly querying the TABLE breaks my connection as well as spiking the CPU usage to 99%)

So my hunch is that the flushing process has stopped working since some time in September. The problem is that I do not know where any of the logs are stored for the flushing process or how to rebuild the index without serious downtime on my live service.

Does full text indexes have a maximum size or do they sometimes bug out and need to be manually handled?

System info) AWS RDS Aurora DB 5.7 Mysql

To see the status of my full text index I first set innodb_ft_aux_table="DATABASE_NAME/TABLE_NAME", then queried all Fulltext related tables for hints. (ref: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-information-schema-fulltext_index-tables.html)

The CACHE table is working fine, but I can't directly query the TABLE table. Even if I were able to directly query for the rows, I doubt it will tell me anything useful.

Comment: What is your biggest table name?  Please post TEXT results of A) SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE name LIKE "biggest_table"';  and B) SHOW CREATE TABLE biggest_table; for analysis.

Comment: Please post TEXT results of SELECT * FROM information_schema.innodb_ft_config; for consideration.

Comment: Add some info on table size (number rows, etc).  Then post a bug report at bugs.mysql.com